# How to find out the last item in a list of string?

Tags: genie

Working with **list of string** is pretty straightforward in Genie. I was wondering if one could locate the last added item with something similar to [-1] in python.

Taking the example from Genie's tutorial:

```
[indent=4]

init

    /* test lists */
    var l = new list of string

    l.add ("Genie")
    l.add ("Rocks")
    l.add ("The")
    l.add ("World")

    for s in l
        print s

    print " "

    print l[-1]
```

### Aim

My expectative was that the l[-1] bit would point to "World" item. However it gives me the error at execution time:

```
ERROR:arraylist.c:954:gee_array_list_real_get: assertion failed: (index >= 0)
/tmp/geany_run_script_X6D4JY.sh: line 7: 13815 Abortado                (imagem do núcleo gravada)/tmp/./test
```

### Question

The gee array clearly only works with positive indexes, is there any other way to get the last added item on an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gee list has a `last` method:

```
print( l.last() )
```

A Gee list's length is found with the `size` property:

```
print( l[ l.size -1 ] )
```

A Gee list can also be sliced with only the last element:

```
for s in l[l.size-1:l.size]
    print( s )
```

Answer (score 0):

In python

```
last_index = len(a) - 1

print a[last_index]
```

In vala or genie,

```
last_index = a.length - 1

print a[last_index]
```

Comment: It seems that the Gee.Array list does not have a len or length method... Neither I could find a len function at valadoc...

Comment: @Luís,  `An array is created by using "array of type name" followed by the fixed size of the array e.g. var a = new array of int[10] to create an array of 10 integers. The length of such an array can be obtained by the length member variable e.g. var count = a.length.` Source : https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie` Please let me know if this is wrong..